# Potential Review Bug?

Tags: bug, review-audits

So I got the following review [image]

(and obviously failed), but I had originally selected the downvote as well as the vote count, but when I pressed either of them I got an error (That I don't remember at the moment), and when I tried to comment it would just refresh the page. So my only options would have been to edit which I felt would have been wrong. Instead I would have suggested that Jesse explain how the link worked for him.

Is there a bug that wouldn't let me downvote/comment?

Comment: Downvote means that it's not useful.  It should be flagged for deletion as it's not an answer.  I say that the review is working as intended.

Comment: My first guess is you downvoted first then tried to comment.  And you failed as soon as you commented.  Commenting is as best is a tough issue to deal with in audits because it can be used to be positive, negative, and neutral.  So assuming my guess about your order of actions is correct, it is unfortunate the system triggered a failure since your instinct was going in the right direction (that the post was bad and needed downvoted and improved)

Comment: @Makoto that's a bit unfair.  It is a link-only answer.  There should be an opportunity for improvement before deletion, so the OP here was on the right path by trying to downvote and comment

Comment: I see *nothing* that can be improved in that answer.  It's literally saying "the answer is over at this link", and if that link disappears or goes dark, then we have no usable answer.  What could we ***possibly*** salvage from that answer?

Comment: Maybe not you or I, but the OP?

Comment: @Makoto: Someone could copy the relevant information from that link into a quote block.

Comment: @Makoto others have said it already, but I'll reinforce it.  The [link in question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc645060(v=vs.95).aspx) appears to contain some possibly useful information.  The author of the answer (who I am guessing is the OP of the question-in-question) deserves the opportunity to fix the answer.  We shouldn't delete stuff right away just because it is a link (assuming it isn't spam and is an attempt to answer the question).  The point here is failing an audit because of a downvote and comment is going to far.

Comment: Here we go again.  First, the fact that the OP *has found a solution* is important to the **state of the question**.  Next, the link is appears to be to an official vendor reference.  The idea that such information is useless **and best censored** is *utterly illogical*.

Comment: @Makoto : Deleting link-only (but, otherwise, correct and helpful) answers as a matter of policy is just ridiculous: we are deleting something **definitely** helpful now so it will not **possibly** become useless in the future.

Comment: @Makoto I suppose the main problem here is, that the hint suggests that "downvoting" is a valid option, but the hint is triggered even if you downvoted.

Comment: @MrTux: downvoting is supposed to trigger the "audit passed" on bad audit posts, and vice versa. If that is not the case nowadays, then that is certainly a bug.

Comment: Link-only questions should be deleted per policy. SO never wanted a site with a vast collection of broken links, which is what you'll end up with in the long term if you leave them be. It would give SO a bad reputation, as so many other sites before it. The usefulness of the link is irrelevant, it should be deleted if posted as an answer. Links in comments are ok.

Comment: @Lundin my intentions for this review would have been a downvote and a request that the answerer detail relevant information from the linked article. Over time I feel it would A) Be deleted because he/she never updated the link or B) he/she would edit the post.